# Remote desktop with vmware and usb connexion

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, vmware

I have a windows server 2012 with vmware installed , I have 3 vms ( win xp recomanded because of a software compatibilty ) , I access to those 3 vms from Itium 4030 thin clients over RDP , I have 1 usb device that must be connected to each vm , so I'm asking as when I plug the usb on the thin client , it doesn't show on the rdp session .

so I have decided to plug all the devices into the server where vmware is installed and connect the usb devices to the vms , it works when I use the vms inside the server , but when I'm connected over rdp to the vms I don't see the usb devices at all .

So how can I solve this .

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I haven't fully understood your question when I was answering it. I'll delete my answer and upvote your question instead.